# Swift 3.0 Map viewForAnnotation Not Outputting Proper Callout

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am having trouble understanding the code for viewForAnnotation method and when it is called. My intention is to display a specific callout depending on what color the pin color is. Upon first loading the mapView, the callouts are displayed properly, however after switching view controllers, the callout buttons are not properly displayed according to the pin color. I have a hunch this might have something to do with when viewForAnnotation is called (whether it is called every time the map appears). I am unable to figure out what is wrong because I am not sure what each part of the code does.

```
func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {

    return nil
}

let identifier = "pinAnnotation"


// In particular I am not sure what the code below does

if let pin = annotation as? ColorPointAnnotation {


    if let view = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        view.annotation = annotation
        view.pinTintColor = pin.color ?? .purple

        return view

    } else {

        let view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        view.isEnabled = true

        view.canShowCallout = true

        view.pinTintColor = pin.color ?? .purple

        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn


        if view.pinTintColor == .red || view.pinTintColor == .green {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        } else {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "other"), for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.other), for: .touchUpInside)
            view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        }

        return view
    }
}

if let annotationView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) {
    annotationView.annotation = annotation
    return annotationView
} else {
    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    annotationView.isEnabled = true
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true

    let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

    if annotationView.pinTintColor == .red || annotationView.pinTintColor == .green {

        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.getDirections), for: .touchUpInside)
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    } else {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "other"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MapVC.other), for: .touchUpInside)
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
    }

    return annotationView
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `func mapView(_ map: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?` is a delegate method of `MapViewDelegate`, this method is executed every time that your mapView show an Annotation in a Region, and if is implemented you can show any subclass of `annotationView` as `annotationView` in the map, to show custom callout you need implement this method of `MapViewDelegate`

```
//example code
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    let customCallout = CustomCallout(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.8, height: 50))
   customCallout.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //your color here
   view.addSubView(customCallout)
   //adjust any param you need here
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: To clarify, when you say the mapView shows an annotation in a region, do you mean if the annotation is placed, or if the current view the user sees has an annotation. Also what exactly do you mean with "put any UIView as annotation in the map"?

Comment: @Kevin Yes if the annotation is added in a coordinate that is inside of a region then is showed using this delegate method, if implemented, check my answer again was updated

Comment: @Kevin you are using 2 types of Annotations?, I think missunderstood your question

Comment: There is a use of unresolved identifier CustomCallout. So what you are saying is I can create a callout to my needs in the didSelectView delegate?

Comment: I am having trouble accessing the annotation pin color in this didSelectView delegate. How can I access that? With this I think my answer is solved

Comment: nevermind I've figured it out. THanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @Kevin ok congrats!!, I am glad to help you